# Highlight part of text in textblock not working on all listboxItems

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate, itemcontainergenerator

I'm trying to highlight part of text in a textblock from a listbox datatemplate which in turn is bounded to a property of a custom class by using a textbox to search the list for input text.
 But the problem is that only part of the items are highlighting (most of the ones visible) but when i maximize the window and try to input another character then suddenly all of them gets highlighted my guess where the problem might be is in this piece of code:

```
ListBoxItem listboxItemFound= (ListBoxItem)this.listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(TItem);
```

Since this method is returning a null when the items are not visible but the items are currently in the listbox. 
 Somehow I guess the items listboxItem instances are not yet created  until you scroll down or maximize to view more items.

XAML DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Grid Name="gridOfListbox" Height="25" Margin="0,2">
    <DockPanel Name="dockpanelWithTxtBlock">
      <TextBlock Name="textbloxk" DockPanel.Dock="Left" FontSize="15" TextAlignment="Center">
        <Run Text="" /><Run Background="Yellow" Text="" /><Run Text="{Binding ProductID}" />
      </TextBlock>
    </DockPanel>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

If more code is needed just let me know.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Also if there is any other better way of finding the listboxItem bounded to the custom Item just let me know. Thank you very much!

[Pic of problem] https://i.stack.imgur.com/HViag.png

Comment: Yes, `ListBoxItem`s are only created as needed by default. This is to improve memory usage and performance. Why do you need to find the `ListBoxItem` in order to highlight part of the text in it?

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply. Because I need to find the textblock (to highlight text) associated with that listboxItem (which is associated with the custom class) since the textblock is in a dataTemplate and not accessible in code. What do you suggest? Maybe if there is a way to force the creation of all instances of listboxItems? if you need more code I could send you so we get a better understanding.

Comment: highlighting makes sense only for visible items

Comment: @AnjumSKhan True but what if when the user maximize or scroll down or whatever to view more items, the other now visible listboxItems are not partly highlighted where they should be?

Comment: That highlight of empty makes not sense to me.  Disable container recycling.

Comment: @Paparazzi Highlight of empty at beginning because the user has not typed anything in the textbox used for searching through the Listbox. When he does, this Run is used to highlight text in textblock. If you have a better and simpler way to highlight text in this matter then pls help! :)

Comment: @Merv That is not going to be a dynamic run.  Maybe if you you bound it two way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to fix this is to set [VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing.aspx) to `false` for your `ListBox`. This will cause all of the items to be created right away. The downside to this is if your `ListBox` has many items, your program will use more memory (since more items will be created), and could potentially run slower depending on the number of items.

A better solution to consider would be to have multiple `DataTemplate`s for this - one without the highlight, and one with. You can set a [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) for your `ListBox` (using the [ItemTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property). The selector can choose which template to use based on if the item matches the search term or not.

The tricky part would be writing the template with the highlighted text. You could probably achieve that by having properties on the object the `ListBoxItem` is bound to for the text before the highlighted text, the highlighted text, and then the remaining text.

Comment: This solved my problem of highlighting but as you said it uses more memory and your second suggestion got me lost. Thank you very much! As for now I will use your first fix. I will wait for more answers if not then I will mark it as THE one. Thanks again!